# MySQL - Make an existing field unique without deleting empty entries

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytbl ADD UNIQUE (columnName);
```

This will make a filed a unique index but the command deletes all rows with an empty value, is there any way I can avoid that happening. The field may have NULL values if that helps.

Comment: I don't understand Mysql accept NULL as Unique

Answer (score 1):

Set the "empty" (?) values to NULL and don't use `IGNORE`.  The purpose of `ALTER IGNORE` is to remove duplicate values.  Multiple NULL are not duplicates of each other, since the expression `NULL = NULL` is not true (and is also not false).